# How can I unit test a function that is called by another function

Tags: python, function, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test my program and have decided to unit test the withdraw_cash function. However, it is called by the bank_atm function. I have never called a function that is dependent on another function and am confused about how to do this. Would i use mock and patch to do this?

The tests would be:
check whether entering valid amount
check whether amount is less than balance

```
user = {
    'pin': 1234,
    'balance': 100
}


def withdraw_cash():
    while True:
        try:
            amount = int(input("Enter the amount of money you want to withdraw: "))
        except ValueError as v:
            print(f"Enter correct amount: ")
        else:
            if amount > user['balance']:
                raise ValueError("You don't have sufficient balance to make this withdrawal")  
            else:
                user['balance'] = user['balance'] - amount
                print(f"£{user['balance']}")
                return 
        finally:
            print("Program executed")


def bank_atm():
    count = 0
    to_exit = False
    while (count < 3) and (not to_exit):
        try:
            pin = int(input('Please enter your four digit pin: '))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter correct pin")
            count += 1
        if pin != user['pin']:
            print("Pin does not match.. Try Again")
            count += 1
        else:
            withdraw_cash()
            to_exit = True
    if count == 3:
        print('3 UNSUCCESFUL PIN ATTEMPTS, EXITING')
        print('!!!!!YOUR CARD HAS BEEN LOCKED!!!!!')
    


try:
    bank_atm()
except ValueError as v:
    print(f"ERROR: {v}")
```

Comment: `withdraw_cash` doesn't seem to be dependent on `bank_atm` at all (you could call it directly and it would work fine) so no problem for tests.  You will need to mock the `input` function to simulate user input.

Comment: The withdraw_cash() function does not depend on the bank_atm() function, only the other way around: you could delete the definition of bank_atm(), and withdraw_cash() would still work. Your bigger problem is that both functions rely on both global state and user interaction; those generally make things hard to test. To make your code more testable, you should *refactor* the functions so that they have clear *inputs* (parameters) and *outputs* (return values).

Comment: All the I/O belongs in `bank_atm`. `bank_atm` should also be responsible for verifying that the requested withdrawal amount is present in the account. The only thing `withdraw_cash` should do is take the amount as an argument and decrement the balance.

Comment: ahhh okay, so for testing it is possible to refactor my functions to make clear paramaters, so for example as @chepner has said. Put all the user inputs within the bank_atm function and then have the withdraw function with the argument amount. Testing the withdraw_cash function would be easier then and then if i do want to test the bank_atm function for example to test whether an error is raised if the pin is wrong - i can use mock?

Comment: @IMSoP is it best to steer clear of testing functions that contain user inputs as it gets complicated ?

Comment: If you write `withdraw_atm` correctly, there's nothing to mock. You can also pass the account to update as an argument, rather than hard-coding a global variable.

Comment: As a general rule, I/O should be pushed as far out towards the "edge" of your program as possible. Consider replacing any call to `input` with a function argument, and consider either the *caller* can write to standard output based on the return value of your function, instead of your function writing to standard output immediately.

Comment: aahhh so for example bank_atm(pin, amount) as its parameters removing the inputs all together and the withdraw_cash(amount)??

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the comments.  Put UI interactions in separate functions, such as `getpin` and `getpounds`.  They can then be tested separately from the business functions.  One can either mix manual input with the unittests or automate them by patching sys.stdin/out.  My proof-of-concept experiment, which passes on 3.11.0b3 run from IDLE editor.

```
import sys
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

def getpin(realpin):
    return input('Your pin? ') == realpin

class ManualTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_pin(self):
        print('\n(Enter 1234)')
        self.assertEqual(getpin('1234'), True)
        print('\n(Enter 1)')
        self.assertEqual(getpin('1234'), False)

class MockOut:
    def write(self, string): pass
    # Or 'write = Mock()' to save and check prompts, using mockout.

class MockIn:
    def readline(self):  # input() uses readline, not read.
        return self.line

@patch('sys.stdin', new_callable=MockIn)
@patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=MockOut)
class AutoTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_pin(self, mockout, mockin):
        mockin.line='1234\n'  # input removes '\n' if present.
        self.assertEqual(getpin('1234'), True)
        mockin.line='1233'
        self.assertEqual(getpin('1234'), False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: omg wow, thank you, but is it possible you could explain a bit more on what you have done so I can undertsand. I am not the greatest programmer. I have refactored my code by cutting it up into multiple different functions as you said and I would very much love to see how i can implement this when i unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I have now refactored my program, by breaking it down into separate functions as you said but when I try and run a test specifically for one function, it runs the whole thing and asks for input from each function. I feel like testing each function individually will have to require specific parameters not dependent on the other function.

```
user = {
    'pin': 1234
}

def withdraw_cash(amount):
    balance_account = 100
    if amount > balance_account:
        raise ValueError("You don't have sufficient balance to make this withdrawal")
    else:
        new_balance = balance_account - amount
        return new_balance
    
    
def get_pin():
    count = 0
    to_exit = False
    while (count < 3) and (not to_exit):
        try:
            pin = int(input('Please enter your four digit pin: '))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter correct pin")
            count += 1
        if pin != user['pin']:
            print("Pin does not match.. Try Again")
            count += 1
        else:
            return get_amount(pin)
            #return pin         
    if count == 3:
        a = '3 UNSUCCESFUL PIN ATTEMPTS, EXITING \n !!!!!YOUR CARD HAS BEEN LOCKED!!!!!'
        return a 
            


def get_amount(pin):
    while True:
        try:
            amount = int(input("Enter the amount of money you want to withdraw: "))
        except ValueError as v:
            print(f"Enter correct amount: ")
        else:
            #print(amount)
            return withdraw_cash(amount)
    #return amount

try:
    get_pin()
except ValueError as v:
    print(f"ERROR: {v}")
```